# Why isn't the value updated?

Tags: java

It is a very basic question, but I don't seem to understand why this doesn't work. As far as I know, `a` and `b` would be pointers (in C thinking) to Integer objects. Why is the output `3 2` and not `3 3`? I would have expected the value of b to also be incremented when incrementing a.

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(2);
a = b;
a++;
System.out.print(a + " " + b);
```

Comment: Why do you think b should be 3?

Comment: `a++` makes `a` refer to something new, without changing the `Integer` object that it referred to previously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, in case of java, the term used is an object 'reference' and not a 'pointer'. Basically it means that its a logical reference to the actual object.

Further more as already noted by Lagerbaer, its [autoboxing-unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) that is transparent which effectively increments the value, creates a new object and then assigns it back to the reference.

So at the end of the increment operation, there are two objects instead of one.

The increment operation after unboxing would probably look something like this :

```
a = Integer.valueOf(a.intValue()++);
```

Answer (score 4):

The keyword here is auto-boxing

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Basically, the java compiler automatically converts between the `Integer` class and the primitive type `int` in the "appropriate" context. One such context is assignment.

Answer (score 4):

`Integer` is immutable, and `a++`, like `a = a + 1`, sets `a` to refer to a different immutable object.

In other words: `a = b` sets `a` to refer to the same object as `b`, but after `a++`, `a` and `b` refer to different objects again.

It is *not* equivalent to the C code that I suspect you're thinking of;

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
*a = 1;
int *b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
*b = 2;
a = b;
(*a)++;
```

Thinking about Java references in terms of C pointers, or C++ references, easily leads the mind astray.

Comment: So after a = b they'd be the same object? Or would autoboxing apply *before* that?

Answer (score 2):

Integer is an immutable type, therefore you can't change the value within the method.

```
a = Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the `a++` instruction you have:

```
      +---------+
a --->| Integer |
b --->|    2    |
      +---------+
```

Both `a` and `b` pointing at the same `Integer` object with value 2.

With the `a++` instruction, Java [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) does these steps automatically for you:

1. Convert the `Integer` with value 2 to a primitive type `int` with value 2.
2. Increment the primitive value `int` to 3.
3. Convert the primitive type `int` with value 3 to an `Integer` with value 3, which will give you a new instance. As other pointed out, `Integer` is an [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12370544/2654518) class, so you get different objects for different values.

So you end up with:

```
      +---------+         +---------+
a --->| Integer |   b --->| Integer |
      |    2    |         |    3    |
      +---------+         +---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the value of a which will does not have any affect on the value of be as `b` is not related to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sean already answered, Integer (just like String) is immutable, that means it's value can't be changed. So your call to `a++` actually created a new Integer with value a+1 and stored that as `a`. Meanwhile b is still pointing at the old Integer.

This can be shown by comparing the References (`==` operator). Before `a++` `a==b` returns `true` (same reference/object). After `a++` `a==b` returns `false`, as `a` is now pointing at a new Integer object.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think b should be 3? You never change that value!

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);     // a is 1
Integer b = new Integer(2);     // b is 2
a = b;                          // a now is 2
a++;                            // a now is 3
System.out.print(a + " " + b);
```

Comment: It's easy to see why OP would think that. In Java, objects are always treated as *references*. If it wasn't for autoboxing/unboxing, then the code makes a and b refer to the same object and thus changing a would also change b.